# Getting nullpointer exception while executing query in JPA using Hibernate 5.1.2 as JPA vendor

Tags: hibernate, jpa, weblogic12c, java-6

I'm trying to upgrade my application from OpenJPA implementation 1.0.1 which was using JPA 1.0 to Hibernate 5.1.2

I'm getting nullpointer exception when trying to to call geResultList on a Entity class.

My Sample classes are below: (I've changed the class names as I can not share my original source code. But the mapping are same.)

1) Class Charger  (Representing a sort of mobile charger that has 2 Pin)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Charger")
class ChargerEntityExt5 extends ChargerEntity1Abstract implements Serializable {

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="chargerEntityExt5",targetEntity=PortEntityExt5.class,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
public List<PinEntityExt5> pinEntityExtList;

public List<PinEntityExt5> getPinEntityExtList() {
    return pinEntityExtList;
}

public void setPinEntityExtList(List<PinEntityExt5> pinEntityExtList) {
    this.pinEntityExtList = pinEntityExtList;
}

 }
```

2)

```
@MappedSuperclass
class ChargerEntity1Abstract implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
public Long Id;

@Column(name="CHARGER_ID")
public String chargerId;


// *** Constructor ****
public ChargerEntity1Abstract() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ChargerEntity [cpeId=" + Id!=null? Id.toString():""  + 
            ", chargerId=" + chargerId!=null? chargerId.toString():""  + "]";
}

public Long getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getChargerId() {
    return chargerId;
}

public void setChargerId(String chargerId) {
    this.chargerId = chargerId;
}

 }
```

3) every charger has 2 pins so I've declared a bi-directional one to many mapping between Charger and pin.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PIN")
class PinEntityExt5 extends PinEntity1Abstract implements Serializable{

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name="CHARGER_ID", referencedColumnName="CHARGER_ID",  insertable= false, updatable = false)
private ChargerEntityExt5 chargerEntityExt5;

public ChargerEntityExt5 getChargerEntityExt5() {
    return chargerEntityExt5;
}

public void setChargerEntityExt5(ChargerEntityExt5 chargerEntityExt5) {
    this.chargerEntityExt5 = chargerEntityExt5;
}

}
```

4) PIN Entity has 2 properties. CHARGER_ID and PIN_NUMBER. this 2 field defines one record in the PIN table uniquely. So I've declared a  IDclass (ChargerPin) for representing the composite key

```
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(ChargerPin.class)
class PinEntity1Abstract implements Serializable{

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="CHARGER_ID", nullable = true)
public String chargerId;

@Id
@Column(name="PIN_NUMBER", nullable = true)
public Long pin;

public PinEntity1Abstract() {
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PinEntity [chargerId=" + chargerId + 
            ", port=" + pin!=null? pin.toString():""  + "]";
}


public String getChargerId() {
    return chargerId;
}


public void setChargerId(String chargerId) {
    this.chargerId = chargerId;
}


public Long getPin() {
    return pin;
}


public void setPin(Long pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
}

}



class ChargerPin implements java.io.Serializable{

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String chargerId;

private Long pin;

// **** Constructor *****
public ChargerPin() {
}

public ChargerPin(String kapId, Long port) {
    this.chargerId = kapId;
    this.pin = port;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "kapId [chargerId=" + chargerId!=null? chargerId.toString():"" +
            ", port=" + pin!=null? pin.toString():""  + "]";
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    int kap = chargerId != null ?(Integer.parseInt(chargerId)):0;
    int kap_port = pin!=null?(pin).intValue():0;
    result = prime * result + kap;
    result = prime * result + kap_port;
    return result;

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //return ((o instanceof CpePort) && (kapId.equalsIgnoreCase(((CpePort) o).getKapId())) && (port == (((CpePort) o).getPort())));
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof CpePort1))
        return false;
    ChargerPin other = (ChargerPin) obj;
    if (chargerId == null) {
        if (other.chargerId != null)
            return false;
    } else if ((other.chargerId != null) && chargerId.equals(other.chargerId)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (pin == null) {
        if (other.pin != null)
            return false;
    } else if ((other.pin != null) && (pin != other.pin))
        return false;

    return true;
}

public String getChargerId() {
    return chargerId;
}

public void setChargerId(String chargerId) {
    this.chargerId = chargerId;
}

public Long getPin() {
    return pin;
}

public void setPin(Long pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
}

}
```

5) Now while I'm invoking the below query I'm getting a nullPointer exception with Empty satck trace.

```
public class HibernateTestClass {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EntityManager em = null;

    List<ChargerEntityExt5> ChargerList = null;

    Query query = null;
    String queryString = "SELECT ce FROM ChargerEntityExt5 ce WHERE ce.chargerId=?1";
    try {

        try {
            em = createEntityManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        query = em.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter(1, "110284026");
        ChargerList = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println(ChargerList.size());

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e); 
    } finally{
        em.close();
    }

    }

public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {

    entityManagerFactory =     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("polcaincapu");
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
}
```

Can you please look into this bug. 
Earlier I was trying with Hibernate 5.1.1. version and then the code was throwing error as "Error accessing field by reflection for persistent property". 
Then I changed the code base to use Hibernate version 5.1.2 and then without change of source code the exception got changed into Nullpointer exception.

down vote

This is the full stack trace of the exception. Do you know why this is coming at all:

java.lang.NullPointerException at ChargerEntity1Abstract.toString(EmbeddedIDTester.java:462) at org.hibernate.pretty.MessageHelper.addIdToCollectionInfoString(MessageHelper.java:362) at org.hibernate.pretty.MessageHelper.collectionInfoString(MessageHelper.java:333) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:62) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:121) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88) at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2004) at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:567) at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:249) at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:563) at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:731) at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:918) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:149) at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167) at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4002) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1142) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:167) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2762) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2741) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978) at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075) at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033) at dk.tdc.visitation.polcalink.resource.dbResource.polcadb.inca.servingfp.EmbeddedIDTester.main(EmbeddedIDTester.java:47)

Comment: I've set verbose during executing the attached java class "HibernateTestClass.java" in a stand alone mode. And I'm getting the below NullPointerException along with org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.

Even though, I'm using EAGER fetching for all the collections

Comment: I can see that the first LazyInitializationException is coming from the below "Loaded org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollecti‌​on$DelayedOperation from file:/T:/External/hibernate/5.1.2/hibernate-core-5.1.2.Final‌​.jar" * And then the Nullpointer exceptionis coming from the below "org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.ConcurrentReference‌​HashMap$Values from file:/T:/External/hibernate/5.1.2/hibernate-core-5.1.2.Final‌​.jar"

Comment: I've also reported a BUG in Hibernate Support but I'm not getting any answer.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11229

Comment: Hi @Neil,

There is no stack trace coming in the log. Only the NPE is getting printed if I print the exception. The stacktrace, detailMessage and Cause is empty in the exception.

Comment: Ok. I've now printed the stacktrace and I can see that the nullpointer exception is coming in the overrriden toString() method of the ChargerEntity1Abstract class. I've commented it out. I'll run in my local server and get back.

Comment: Hi @Neil,I've posted below the full stack trace. can you please help to understand why the NPE is coming in the toString() method of the ChargerEntity1Abstract class.

Comment: Why not read it ? EmbeddedIDTester.java:462 Only you know what is line 462 of that class, and consequently only you know what is null

Comment: The line 462 is containing the below



     @Override
     public String toString() {
     return "ChargerEntity [cpeId=" + Id!=null? Id.toString():""  + 
            ", chargerId=" + chargerId!=null? chargerId.toString():""  + "]";
      }

here I'm doing all the necessary null check.

Comment: The issue is coming from the class org.hibernate.pretty.MessageHelper.addIdToCollectionInfoString(MessageHelper.java:362) 

This method in the hibernate core.

  private static void addIdToCollectionInfoString(CollectionPersister persister, Serializable id, SessionFactoryImplementor factory, StringBuilder s)
  {    Type ownerIdentifierType = persister.getOwnerEntityPersister()
      .getIdentifierType();    if (id.getClass().isAssignableFrom(ownerIdentifierType
      .getReturnedClass())) {     s.append(ownerIdentifierType.toLoggableString(id, factory));}else{s.append(id.toString());}}